# how to send already prepared in string http request in C#

Tags: c#, http

**Http request as string C#**

I want to send http request as it is given to me from user without any changing.

From user i get string

```
  GET / HTTP/1.1 
  Host: examplesite.com 
  Content-Length: 15
```

So i want to send it as it is without any changing or parsing, is it any library to do this in C#?

Comment: Do you really need to send the request using C#? Otherwise you can use Fiddler -> Composer -> Raw

Comment: This is not possible.  There are requirements around sending valid requests that the .Net framework do to make sure it's valid.  For example, if a user gave you `Content-Length: 0` with a content length greater than zero, it's invalid.

Comment: You can send the message with `TcpClient` but you will have to handle what `HttpClient` does for you: response parsing, security challenge...

Comment: Guys, his question is pretty clear and I am sure, he knows about other libs for which he needs to parse the string and then do stuff !

Comment: The point is i want to send invalid http requests because i'm making application to automate web site pentesting.

Answer (score 0):

How are you capturing the users prepared URL?

With the least amount of information available if you trying to create a simple request you can use the following:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        // User Prepared Url
        var url = "https://www.google.com";

        // Create a 'WebRequest' object with the specified url. 
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url); 

        // Send the 'WebRequest' and wait for response.
        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse(); 

        // Release resources of response object.
        myWebResponse.Close();
    }
```

There is no logic in checking that the Url is valid etc.